# Why this OCaml patterning matching doesn't compile?

Tags: pattern-matching, ocaml

I have a module interface

```
module type Enum = sig
type t
val toInt : t -> int
val fromInt : int -> t
end
```

Then I have a module

```
module Navigability : Enum = struct
type t=
AB
| BA
| Both
| None

let toInt = function
| BA   -> -65536
| Both -> -1
| None -> 0
| AB   -> 65535

let fromInt = function
| -65536 -> BA  
| -1     -> Both
| 0      -> None
| 65535  -> AB  
| _ -> None

end
```

Once I add the following function, the code can not be compile:

```
let fun = function
| Navigability.t.BA   -> false
| Navigability.t.Both -> true
| Navigability.t.None -> false
| Navigability.t.AB   -> true
```

If I put it inside the module and cancel the interface, it works.

Can anyone tell me why and how?

Comment: As a side note, `fun` is an OCaml keyword and should not be used as a function name.

Comment: @PatJ ah, I changed the name to fun when I post it here thank you

Answer (score 2):

When you write `Navigability: Enum` you're "sealing" the module so that its interface is limited to exactly what's in `Enum`. The values `BA` and so on aren't in there.

Answer (score 2):

A `module type` is a strict specification of what will be visible outside of modules bound to it. So, as Jeffrey Scofield said in his answer, typing `module Navigability : Enum` makes sure that the only things known outside of `Navigability` will be the ones defined in `Enum`, and your type constructors are not part of that.

A simple way to ensure the visibility of your type is to declare it outside of your module and then bound it with a `with` clause:

```
type nav =
AB
| BA
| Both
| None

module Navigability : Enum with type t = nav = struct

type t = nav

(* put other definitions here *)

end

let f = function
| BA   -> false
| Both -> true
| None -> false
| AB   -> true
```

As a side note, your construction `Navigability.t.AB` was incorrect, it should simply be `Navigability.AB`. Also, `fun` can't be used as a function or variable name as it's a keyword.

If you want your navigation type to be only accessed through `Navigability`, you can keep your definition while removing the `Enum` constraint. Nothing will stop you from using `Navigability` as a `Enum` anyway later.